# Show that $c\mapsto c+\langle p(x) \rangle$ is a field monomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a field, and $p(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ an irreducible polynomial. We want to show that $$\phi: F \longrightarrow F[x]/ \langle p(x) \rangle,$$
$$c\mapsto \phi (c):=c+\langle p(x) \rangle$$ is a field monomorphism.

**Proof:**

- We have that $\phi(c_1+c_2)=(c_1+c_2)+\langle p(x) \rangle = (c_1+\langle p(x) \rangle) + (c_2+\langle p(x) \rangle)=\phi(c_1)+\phi(c_2)$. Working by this way, $\phi(c_1\cdot c_2)=\cdots =\phi(c_1)\cdot \phi (c_2)$.
- If $\phi(c_1)=\phi(c_2) \iff c_1+\langle p(x) \rangle=c_2+\langle p(x) \rangle \iff (c_1-c_2)+\langle p(x) \rangle=\langle p(x) \rangle \iff c_1-c_2 \in \langle p(x) \rangle \iff \exists\ q(x)\in F[x] : c_1-c_2 =q(x)\cdot p(x)$. But now, if we take degrees from both sides, we take that 
  $$\deg (c_1-c_2)=\deg q(x)+\deg p(x),$$
  where $\deg (c_1-c_2)=0$, if $c_1\neq c_2$ or $\deg (c_1-c_2)=-\infty$, if $c_1=c_2$. From the other side, $\deg q(x)\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{-\infty \}$.

My question, now, is: Can from this conclude that obligatory $\deg (c_1-c_2)=-\infty \implies c_1=c_2$, so $\phi$ is injective, and finally monomorphism?

*Thank you in advance.*

Comment: Looks good. Note that $\phi$ is NOT bijective; it is only injective.

Comment: @KennyWong Thank you for your comment. Of course, only injective ( i corrected it).

Comment: By the way, any field morphism is either injective or zero. This is because a field morphism is also a ring morphism, and the kernel of a ring morphism is an ideal. But since all non-zero elements in a field are invertible, it follows that any non-zero ideal in a field contains $1$, and hence, is equal to the entire field. So there are two possibilities: either the kernel is zero, or the kernel is the whole field, i.e. either the field morphism is zero, or it is injective.

Comment: P.S. I suppose there is no such thing as a "zero morphism between fields" anyway, if you insist that $0 \neq 1$..